# Why are extra empty rows generated in mysql table when using php insert variables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have tried to insert variable to mysql table from submitted html form. However, I observed that 3 rows is generated while I have just inserted 1 row of data variable. The problem disappeared when the data is not variable. This problem annoyed me very much. Hope problems can be solved. Thank you very much.

Below is the coding of creating the table:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Server Database</title>
</head>
<body>
<span style='font-size:24;font-weight:bold;'>Server Database</span>
<br /><br />

<?php
$host="localhost";
$port=3306;
$socket="";
$user="root";
$password="";
$dbname="";

$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)
    or die ('Could not connect to the database server' .       mysqli_connect_error());

echo "it work"."<br>";

$SCusName=$_POST['CusName'];
$SCusChiName=$_POST['CusChiName'];
$SDate=$_POST['Date'];

$sql = "CREATE DATABASE db";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Database created successfully"."<br>";
} else {
    echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
}

mysqli_select_db($conn,"db")
    or die ('cannot select');

$sql = "CREATE TABLE Requests (
RequestNumber INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
CustomerName VARCHAR(50),
ChineseName VARCHAR(50),
DateOfRequest VARCHAR(30)
)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table Requests created successfully"."<br>";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO Requests (CustomerName, ChineseName, DateOfRequest)
VALUES ('".$SCusName."', '".$SCusChiName."', '".$SDate."');";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully"."<br>";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$sql = "SELECT BbKeyID, CustomerName, ChineseName FROM Requests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "BbKeyID: " . $row["BbKeyID"]. " CustomerName: " .    $row["CustomerName"]. " ChineseName: " . $row["ChineseName"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The result in mysql table become contains three row as follow with a message 3 row(s) returned:
The first row contains correct data while the other two rows are empty in value only with the auto-incremented RequestNumber. Is the RequestNumber make the problems?

1     Result 1     Result 2     Result 3

2

3

The empty values are not NULL.

If the insert data is changed to:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Requests (CustomerName, ChineseName, DateOfRequest)
VALUES ('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC')";
```

The result become correct and only one row given out as follow.

1     Result 1     Result 2     Result 3

Please help me to solve the problem. Thank you very much..

Comment: I **HIGHLY, HIGHLY, HIGHLY** recommend not creating SQL queries through string concatenation.  You open yourself to all sorts of SQL injection problems.  Create a parameterized query and pass your values into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You run your `INSERT` query EVERY TIME the page is loaded, even if no form was submitted. So if the page is fetched via `GET`, you'll have undefined `$_POST` data, and insert empty strings.

You should have at least

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   ... do db insert stuff here ...
}
```

to "hide" the code from non-post requests.

And you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).  Enjoy getting your server pwn3d.